# Can't import dash_core_components

Tags: python, import, plotly-dash, systemexit

I installed dash on ubuntu 18.04:
pip3 install dash.
The version of dash says 1.16.0

Then I have a test program, test.py, and I get the following error. What is wrong?

```
import plotly
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc   <<<<<<<<<<<<< error here:
   Exception has occurred:SystemExit
    1
      File "..../test.py, line 3, in <module>
        import dash_core_components as dcc
      File "..../test.py, line 2, in <module>
       import dash
```

Comment: Is this the full error message? If not, can you share the whole thing?

Comment: Yes that is all. I'm running this in Visual Studio Code. If I run it on the command line I get this: python3 test.py
Dash was not successfully imported. Make sure you don't have a file named 
'dash.py' in your current directory.

Comment: Ok. I've seen that before. There's almost certainly another file in your directory that's causing trouble. Do you have a `help.py` or `test.py`? Get rid of that and try again.

Comment: Interesting! My initial test program was called test.py. I had no clue that that was an invalid name. It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sometimes happens with a file in the directory called `test.py`. Removing that file should resolve the error.